# Why does buildah fail mounting overlays?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, buildah

I am running buildah(quay.io/containers/buildah) in a gitlab CI/CD pipeline(kubernetes pod), but it fails building images.

`buildah bud .` returns:

```
mount /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay, flags: 0x1000: permission denied
time="2023-05-03T13:02:06Z" level=warning msg="failed to shutdown storage: \"mount /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay, flags: 0x1000: permission denied\""
failed with exit code 125
```

Buildah inside of the container is running as root, and I made sure that the overlay module is loaded `lsmod | grep overlay`.
I also read the [troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/containers/buildah/blob/main/troubleshooting.md), but it only mentions issues in rootless mode.

What could cause issues while mounting overlay filesystems?
And which component could be causing the problem(`kubernetes`, `buildah`,`gitlab-ci-cd`,...)?

Thanks in advance :)